# Submit form ng-repeat for ng-model angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to submit to **form** with `ng-repeat` values for `input text` - but error where I submit it

**HTML :**

```
//there is html to view ng-repeat angular.js
<form method="post" ng-controller="FoodCtrl" ng-submit="addCart()">
    <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left" >  
        <img  ng-src=""  ng-click="" >
        <p style="position:absolute;right:-25px;">
            <!--INPUT HIDDEN-->
            <input type="text" ng-model='x.id'>
            <input type="text"  ng-model='x.menu'>
            <input type="text" ng-model='x.harga'>

            <button type="submit" class="button button-balanced button-clear icon ion-android-cart">  </button> 
        </p>

        <h2> {{x.menu}} </h2>

        <p>Harga: Rp {{x.harga}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

**JS:**

Here is **JS** for controller `angular.js`

```
$scope.addCart = function() {
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'server/menu/add_cart',
        headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
        data    : JSON.stringify({ id: $scope.id ,menu: $scope.menu , harga:$scope.harga })
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Not clear what a problem are you facing? Please add more info.

Comment: Add which type of error you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have passed the item into the ng-click function where it is saved into another scope variable and then it is accessed in the addCart function which is called on ng-click,

**Changes to be done:**

**In HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" class="button  button-balanced button-clear   icon ion-android-cart" ng-click="saveIndex(x)">  </button>
```

**In JS:**

```
$scope.saveIndex=function(x){
$scope.currentItem=x;
}
```

**In addCart function:**

```
$scope.addCart=function(){
console.log("id "+$scope.currentItem.id+"menu "+$scope.currentItem.menu+"harga"+$scope.currentItem.harga)


     $http({
     method  : 'POST',
     url     : 'server/menu/add_cart',
     headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
     data    : JSON.stringify({ 
id: $scope.currentItem.id ,
menu: $scope.currentItem.menu, harga:$scope.currentItem.harga })
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 });
}
```

This is a working snippet as shown below,

```js
var app = angular.module('TryApp', []);
app.controller('FoodCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items=[{id:"232",
 menu:"sdfdsf",
 harga:"adfsdf"
},
{id:"235",
 menu:"sdfdsf",
 harga:"adfsdf"
},
{id:"237",
 menu:"sdfdsf",
 harga:"adfsdf"
},
];
$scope.addCart = function() {

  }
$scope.addCart=function(){
console.log("id "+$scope.currentItem.id+"menu "+$scope.currentItem.menu+"harga"+$scope.currentItem.harga)
                $http({
         method  : 'POST',
         url     : 'server/menu/add_cart',
         headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
         data    : JSON.stringify({ 
id: $scope.currentItem.id ,
menu: $scope.currentItem.menu, harga:$scope.currentItem.harga })
     }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
     });

}
$scope.saveIndex=function(x){
$scope.currentItem=x;
} 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" ng-app="TryApp" ng-controller="FoodCtrl" ng-submit="addCart()">
            <div ng-repeat="x in items"> 
                <img  ng-src=""  ng-click="" >
                <p style="position:absolute;right:-25px;">
                <!--INPUT HIDDEN-->
                <input type="text" ng-model='x.id'>
                <input type="text"  ng-model='x.menu'>
                <input type="text" ng-model='x.harga'>

                <button type="submit" class="button  button-balanced button-clear   icon ion-android-cart" ng-click="saveIndex(x)">  </button> 
                </p>

                <h2>  sdfsdf</h2>

                <p>Harga: Rp {{x.harga}} {{currentItem.id}}</p>


            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)if the solution helped you, please don't forget to mark it as the answer,as it will help people who check for such an issue later